# Firebase Cloud Functions to write to Firestore when creating a FirebaseAuth user

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

### TLDR

How can I create a user in FirebaseAuth and then automatically write a user document to Firestore 1) without running the risk that an unfortunately timed network error on the frontend  leading to creating the user but not writing to Firestore and 2) await/listen for the completion of the sign-up process on the frontend? I think you do this with cloud functions but I'm not sure how to implement it properly. This seems like a super common use case so there must be an very simple way to solve this.

### Complete explanation

When creating a user in FirebaseAuth, I want to automatically create a user document in Firestore, but I also want to make sure that my app is resilient to loosing connection or any kind of write network error when creating a user. From what I understand, if I chain a write to Firestore after a user is created in FirebaseAuth, I could theoretically have a situation where a user is created in FirebaseAuth but the connection is interrupted before the write to Firestore happens, which could introduce a bad error into the app.

Since Firebase doesn't support transactions between services (i.e. a transaction to include creating a user with Auth and writing to Firestore), I believe that the only way to ensure the write to Firestore happens is using a Firebase cloud function. This is also the method recommended by the Firebase documentation. Currently, I have a cloud function that fires when a user is created and that creates a document in Firestore. Since it fires when a user is created, the only way to pass a name to it is through the auth display name , which it parses in order to write the user's first and last name to Firestore.

The fields I have for a user are first name, last name, email, UID, and some custom data that's initialized as empty. However, since creating the user only takes an email and password, and not a FirebaseAuth display name, the function is firing before the display name is set:

```
await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
    email: /* email here */,
    password: /* password here */,
);
// The cloud function is firing here and sets the user's name to empty in Firestore
await userCredential.user!.updateDisplayName(
    '${/* first name here */} ${/* last name here*/}',
);
```

Not only is the cloud function not writing the user's name, but this seems like I'm introducing the same problem I'm trying to avoid in that the connection could be interrupted before the name is set. This would be true even if I only store the user's name in auth and only have my custom data in Firestore. I also don't know how to listen to the completion of both the auth signup and then the Firestore write with the cloud function.

So what's best practice? I have two ideas, but both seem not great. I could either 1) have a callable cloud function I can pass all my data to that both signs a user up and writes to firestore, or 2) write to a 'pending changes' collection and have the cloud function listen to that to then do those two actions. But I also don't think I can await/listen to the completion of the signup function on the frontend with both of these solutions.

**Also, should I store the user's first and last name seperately in Firestore or just parse the auth display name?**

Comment: Afaik Firestore handles this situation. You don't need a cloud function. It would be the same issue for any data to be written to the database. See: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline

Answer (score 0):

> How can I create a user in FirebaseAuth and then automatically write a user document to Firestore 1) without running the risk that an unfortunately timed network error on the frontend leading to creating the user but not writing to Firestore

You can trigger a cloud function after account created, see [Extend Firebase Authentication with Cloud Functions](https://Extend%20Firebase%20Authentication%20with%20Cloud%20Functions)

```
exports.writeDataWhenAccountCreated = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
  // Write data to firestore.
});
```

> await/listen for the completion of the sign-up process on the
> frontend?

It could be sercurity issue in some scenario, Because you can't guaranteed client not being reverse engineered, But it depends on what kind of data write to database after account created, You also can check if those data are exists by sercurity rules to prevent unexpected reads or writes from client.